# Unable to remove directory?

Tags: files, directory

I am unable to remove a directory named like this:

`\034\000\000,?IS?#\001\000`

Tried with `rm "\034\000\000,?IS?#\001\000"` with no luck.

How can I delete such a directory?

Comment: Have you tried with `rm -rf` or `rmdir` after removing its content?

Comment: have you tried to use single quotes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undeletable directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218491/undeletable-directory)

Comment: this is not dupplicate, problem seems related to finding proper filename.

Answer (score 2):

\034 is code for quote, you are likely trying to delete the **string** \034...

I would suggest you use

```
rm -irf *IS*
```

from above, `-rf` flag will ensure deletion, while `-i` will ask before deleting (so other dir file will be spared).

next, it looks unatural to have null byte in filename, I would suggest unmount filesystem and `fsck`.

Answer (score 0):

Try **`rm -fr *IS*`** to delete "\034\000\000,?IS?#\001\000" directory